# How to add array data into FusionCharts

Tags: jquery, arrays, fusioncharts

I make API to retrieve data from the server and then looping to each data. I will do next is to show the data into FusionCharts. The data retrieved from the server is appropriate for what I need.

How do I make an array that I have made FusionCharts can be entered into the data to be displayed with the code below?

```
function URLSitePath() {
    var siteUrl = document.location.origin;
    return siteUrl;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: URLSitePath() + '/report/apigetdatapermonth',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        async : true,
        success: function(result) {
            var arr = [];
            $.each(result.items, function() {
                arr.push({
                    label:this.month,
                    value:this.total_subs
                });
            });

            FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'column2d',
                renderAt: 'chart-container',
                width: '100%',
                height: '350',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "Transvision subscribe via website",
                        "xAxisName": "Month",
                        "yAxisName": "Total Subs",
                        "numberPrefix": "",
                        "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
                        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                        "borderAlpha": "20",
                        "canvasBorderAlpha": "0",
                        "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                        "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                        "placevaluesInside": "1",
                        "rotatevalues": "1",
                        "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
                        "showXAxisLine": "1",
                        "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
                        "divlineColor": "#999999",
                        "divLineIsDashed": "1",
                        "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                        "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                        "subcaptionFontSize": "14"
                    },
                    "data": [arr]
                }
            }).render();
            });

        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error.');
        }
    });
});
```

Generally FusionCharts require data into an array like

```
{
    "label": "Jan",
    "value": "100"
},
{
    "label": "Feb",
    "value": "200"
},
{
    "label": "Mar",
    "value": "300"
}
```

How do I get the data I have on the `arr` variable  can be displayed on the data portion of FusionCharts? I tried directly by giving the code `"data": [arr]` but failed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the array to FusionCharts like this

```
var arr = [{
    "label": "Jan",
    "value": "100"
},
{
    "label": "Feb",
    "value": "200"
},
{
    "label": "Mar",
    "value": "300"
}]
```

And then in fusion charts data pass `"data" = arr`

For more info see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4asqwj6L/)

Comment: Hi @Venkatesan Thanks for your help..I can see, but how I can combine my data provide using jQuery loop $.each code above into the array's data?

Comment: @BerthoJoris: You could place a [ before the data is added to the arr variable and once the data is completely added, you can add a closing].

Comment: Thanks @Venkatesan

Comment: That may not work @BerthoJoris. I believe just providing arr should help